# Image unrecognized ios

Tags: ios, uiimage

I have an UIImage that I assign to an UIImageView.

When I do :

```
UIImage *picto = [UIImage imageNamed:@"animage.png"];
UIImageView *imageView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:picto];
```

it works, but when I do :

```
UIImage *picto = [UIImage imageNamed:@"animage2.png"];
UIImageView *imageView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:picto];
```

My image 2 isn't displayed, the grammar is correct and my image exist in the project...

By the way, the second image is not displayed just because it name

Comment: please describe your problem

Comment: Are you using an asset catalog (`.xcassets` file)?

Comment: create your image array and apply `imageNamed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this format :

```
UIImageView *icon_bg=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
icon_bg.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"animage.png"];
[Cell.contentView addSubview:icon_bg];
```

Comment: it was a size problem but thanks for your help, this synthax is better.